# How to format a date in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

I have a database with a table, and it has a field with datetime type. When I collect data from that field and show it in PHP, it shows "Oct 9 2012 2:06PM". I want to convert its format to "10/09/2012 14:06:00". Please note that before I convert it, it doesn't have "second" and I want it have "00" seconds after conversion.

How can I format this date in PHP?

Comment: This is a question that any beginner's date tutorial would cover. Did you try figuring out how to do it before asking here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should familiarize yourself with PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function.

A similar date format could be created with:

```
$formatted = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime($dateFromDb));
```

The [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) call on the date from the database will be required first in-order to convert the date into a Unix timestamp which can then be passed to the `date()` function (for formatting).

Comment: Thanks! it work perfectly!  Could I ask one more question?  How can I collect part value of datetime? such as year or month or date...?

Comment: @user1730500 You can use something like `$year = date('Y', strtotime($dateFromDb));` to get the year, or any individual piece as well. If you're going to get a lot of individual pieces, I'd recommend storing the timestamp in another variable first, like `$time = strtotime($dateFromDb); $year = date('Y', $time);` (this will save some processing time!)

Answer (score 1):

You can use function `strtotime()` to parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp, so you can use `date()` function to parse your format!